# Serving Django static files using mod_wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, django-staticfiles

I have heard that Django static files should be deployed directly from the web server, not through Django itself.  I'm using mod_wsgi -- does anyone know how I would configure it to serve my django static files?

Comment: Do you mean Nginx or Apache? You should configure the server itself, not mod_wsgi. Add the corresponding tag to your question.

Comment: Did you think to look at the Django documentation, where this question is discussed at length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango